# How does IPrincipal gets its roles?

Tags: asp.net, sitemapprovider, iprincipal, isinrole, isaccessibletouser

I need to get know how `SiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser()` works.

Built-in `XmlSiteMapProvider` calls `HttpContext.User.IsInRole()` which uses `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal` in case of forms authentication.

Where does the current user gets its roles? Which provider loads this kind of information? I want to overload it and use custom logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this by implementing a RoleProvider. Check out these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx

Comment: To be more precise, `public override bool IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName) { }`

Comment: Yes. As an aside, two extension methods I like to make to extend the base-class of User (System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal) are "IsInAnyRole(string[])" and "IsInAllRoles(string[])" to check if a user is in ALL the roles or ANY of the roles in the passed in array. These can be useful for complex role logic. Implementation as your own exercise.

Answer (score 2):

To use custom logic, you can create your own forms authentication cookie with roles and read it back in Global.asax.

See these:

```
private void SetAuthenticationCookie(int employeeID, List<string> roles)

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/01/securing-an-asp-net-mvc-2-application.aspx